# Tools to make HTML forms send emails automatically

Tags: php, html, email, forms, generator

I've 5 huge ugly forms written in HTML ... I wanna convert those forms to send emails using PHP automatically without going through each one and reading the post variables then constructing the mail code ... There was a tool online once but I cannot find it and I forgot its name ...

Any one can recommend something?

Comment: You want a pre-built script that will magically work with your forms? Not likely.

Comment: Yes ... This exist ... but the project is too old and hasn't been updates since 3 or more years ... Check it out : http://www.webformfactory.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools like this save you time when you're working on a static website but require a contact form. Check this link, it has a couple of options: http://www.html-form-guide.com/form-mail/form-mail-script.html
The whole blog seems to be dedicated to web forms creation.

Best regards!

Comment: Well I used http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php from the page you sent and it worked as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless, you will have to point the action="" to some location.  I suggest setting up a web service that accepts what you post to it.  Then redirect all your old forms action="" option to that web service address.

Comment: Surely, you mean `action=""`?

Comment: Yes, sorry i'll correct.

Comment: Well, this is surely correct but isn't quite exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot